# import charts error with jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter

when I import charts
I get a lots of error
how to solve it?thanks

import charts

[erroe image likes here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFDra.png)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'# i import scipy but still error

Answer (score 0):

Looks like scipy is not installed

Try to install it using your terminal:

```
pip install scipy
```